# Changeset in TFS Build Report

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS2010 to do our builds.  The screenshot below depicts a typical build report from a successful build. The build is a manual build, kicked off by a user at the a desired time and does not have a specific changeset specified on the build definition.

The top line of the build report states that the build was triggered for a particular changeset number (35264), however that changeset number is a changeset which has nothing to do with the associated changesets that were used to generate the build. The changeset number provided at the top of the build report is higher than any of the associated changesets and for a source path which is not referenced in the build definition.  The `Build Explorer` also lists this changeset number in a column labeled 'Source Version'.

I would expect the number at the top of the build report to be changeset 35262, which is the associated changeset with the build. Why would TFS report an arbitrary changeset number when I queue a build? Is this number being reported the current max changeset number in the Team Project Collection at the time of the build?

I am having a difficulty understanding what this changeset number is and what it represents and looking for someone to help clarify this number.

[image: build report screenshot]

Comment: You say that this changeset is not expected; what changeset *would* you expect to see?  Is the changeset you expect earlier or later than this changeset?  What type of build is this?  CI?  Rolling?  Gated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changeset is not specific to a folder or branch. Instead it isba global high watermark.

If you do a checkin anywhere in the system the checkin number will increment and any new builds will use that number as long as they are set to build the latest code.

Comment: So basically, this number indicates the highest possible changeset in the Team Project Collection at the time of the build. If I were to do a get on my source folder(s) for that build where the source changeset was less than or equal to the number specified on the build report, I would have an equivalent snapshot of the 'latest version' of the source which was used to generate the build.